# Integration of R Language with php to take the result from R

Tags: php, r

I have the following R script

```
 #assign data path
    data_path <- "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\R\\work";

    #assign valus to the following three percent
    train_per <- 0.7;
    test_per <- 0.2;
    val_per <- 0.1;


    data <- read.csv(file=paste(data_path,"\\test.csv",sep=""), sep=",");
    train_d <- sort(sample(nrow(data), nrow(data)*train_per));


    train <- data[train_d,];
    rem_train <- data[-train_d,]; 

    test_d <- sort(sample(nrow(rem_train), nrow(data)*test_per));
    test <- rem_train[test_d,];
    validation <- rem_train[-test_d,]; 

    m <- glm(der_var4~.,data=train,family=binomial());

    coef_data <- data.frame(coef(m));
    coef_data[7:8,"column_name"] <- NA;
    coef_data$column_name <- row.names(coef_data);

    write.table(coef_data,file=paste(data_path,"\\coef_data.csv",sep=""),sep=",",row.names=FALSE);

    anova_data <- data.frame(anova(m));
    anova_data[7:8,"column_name"] <- NA;
    anova_data$column_name <- row.names(anova_data);

    write.table(anova_data,file=paste(data_path,"\\anova_data.csv",sep=""),sep=",",row.names=FALSE);
```

The above script is running fine in R.The above script will create two csv files.
But i want to run that script by using my php code .My main goal is to take the values of
the following variables from the php

```
train_per ;
test_per ;
val_per ;
```

and then i have to send the values of above to R script and then i have to run that script from my php code.Please help me i am new to R as well as php.I am trying to use exec function but not reaching anywhere and i have also seen older posts and also surf the net but could not find any solution.

Comment: hint: dont paste file paths together like that, use something like file.path(data_path,"filename.csv") and it'll save you some time.

Answer (score 5):

In your PHP code, use the exec to pass your variable to R
$response is the R response.

```
exec("Rscript /path/to/rcode.R  $a $b ", $response);
$str = $response[0];
$myobj = json_decode($str);

echo $myobj->first_name;
```

In your R code (my exmaple using rcode.R)

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
tmp <- strsplit(args, " ")

a <- as.numeric(tmp[[1]][1])
b <- as.numeric(tmp[[2]][1])


output <- list(first_name="Finau")

library(rjson)
cat(toJSON(output))
```

//You need to use the RJson for R

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON to pass the data back and forth. There's `RJSONIO` package that will help you the R part. I'd rather store your variables in a named list, and serialize them to JSON:

```
lst <- list(
            train_per = train_per,
            test_per = test_per,
            val_per = val_per
            )
res <- toJSON(lst)
cat(res)
```

this piece of code should return JSON encoded list. I'll assume that you're using RApache, since it has PHP-like superglobal called `POST`. Then, on the PHP side, use output buffering:

```
<?php
ob_start();
// call R script here
$resp = json_decode(ob_get_clean());
?>
```

You should test the result by simply `echo`ing it out or by issuing `print_r`. If everything runs smooth, you will get variable values in an associative array elements.

**EDIT:**

You should head over to [RApache homepage](http://rapache.net/), and install it. Learn how to send form data to R scripts - Jeroen Ooms' [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_profilepage&v=fB_7_RZgasg) is a good starting point. Then you can send POST requests with PHP cURL - [link](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl) on David Walsh's blog should be helpful. Of course, this piece of code should be inserted between `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` to capture stuff that R script echoes.

I'm having a *deja-vu* as I'm writing this... something tells me that I've already wrote something similar here. I know that there were a lot of rants about R/PHP integration.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer sir but my goal is to run R script form php code .can you please explain it littile more

Comment: @nilesh1006 please don't _sir_ me, I'm desperately trying to think of myself as a youngster! =) See the edit for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any external program from PHP with the 'exec' function. Read all the warnings on the manual page though. Read them and understand them.

The problem can be that R takes a while to start up, which makes your web page a bit slow. If that is a problem, then you need another solution (possibly running a private Rserve port will do).

I see you say you are trying to use the exec function. Well, how far have you got? What you can do is put the values of your PHP variables on the command line that you create and pass to exec, and then get those values using the R commandArgs() function.