# Extend PHP to communicate with R programming language

Tags: php, c++, c, r, php-extension

I'm on a road to build a PHP extension module to allow PHP to communicate with the R programming language.

My objective for this module is to allow me to run some R function directly from PHP.

I haven't build any extension on PHP before, but I know how to write a php program. I know a little bit about C and C++

I'm interested to hear what the expert advice on this one.

Here's some of the questions I want to know:

1. Is it possible to achieve the above idea?
2. What tools do I need?
3. What is the effective way to do this?

Comment: 1. yes. [this does it for python](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) -so might be of use to your dev efforts. But in the first place see [r-php](http://dssm.unipa.it/R-php/?cmd=home) and [this similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046881/using-r-with-apache-php)

Comment: Thanks violet, I now found the Rserve to explore

Comment: I'm thinking rcom might provide some COM ways to interact with PHP, but there are probably more direct ways to get it done. It would be an interesting development, but the security issues are great. You would really have to take a bottom-up approach in making sure only a very select set of R operations are permissible, and you better make sure a creative hacker couldn't use those permitted to do system harm! I'm thinking from a web PHP interface, of course.

Comment: Great idea Bryan, I'll investigate the rcom as well. I did explore the Rserve but I'm still not satisfy with how it works. Thanks again.

Comment: Just an update, I'm now explore the D-Bus and it's very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the *search* feature at the top-right before you post.

Similar questions have been asked before, see e.g.

- [Pass and get variables between PHP and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675745/pass-and-get-variables-between-php-and-r)
- [Integration of R Language with php to take the result from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104451/integration-of-r-language-with-php-to-take-the-result-from-r)
- [php and R integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033038/php-and-r-integration)

and there are probably more.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, all the above link is not an options for me. I did search around on Google but haven't found someone who develop something similar.